# Filename match and export

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, xargs

I have several files in a folder. I have to match the filenames using a regex pattern. In the regex pattern I have a word which would be a variable. I want all the files matched with the pattern to be moved to a separate directory with an alternate filename replacing the string with which I had made the match.

Eg,

I have many files with filenames having the word foo in the directory like,

```
gadgeagfooafsa
fsafsaffooarwf
fasfsfoofsafff
```

I have to list these files and copy it to another directory replacing the word foo from it. I have specified the new pattern to be "kuh", Like the above files should be copied to the new folder as

```
gadgeagkuhafsa
fsafsafkuharwf
fasfskuhfsafff
```

Finally, can I pipe different commands together to execute these in one line? :)

I had tried this command, but it didn't work, somehow the copy is failing.

```
ls | grep ".*foo[} ].*" | xargs cp -t work/
```

Comment: can you edit , and add what code did you try

Comment: I tried this one, but it didn't work.
ls | grep ".*foo[} ].*" | xargs cp -t work/

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*foo*" -exec bash -c 'fn=${0##*/}; cp "$0" "new_dest/${fn//foo/kuh}"' {} \;
```

- `fn=${0##*/}` - extracting file *basename*
- `${fn//foo/kuh}` - substituting `foo` with `kuh` in filename

Replace/adjust `new_dest` with your current *destination* directory name.

Answer (score 0):

I chose /tmp as the new destination, and only used two of the example files

```
newdest="/tmp"; fp="foo"; np="kuh"; for f in $(find . -type f -name "*$fp*"); do new=$(echo $f| sed  "s/$fp/$np/g"); cp -f $f $newdest/$new ; done
```

which moves and renames the files

```
ls /tmp/*kuh*
/tmp/fsafsafkuharwf  /tmp/gadgeagkuhafsa
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in same folder

with bash

```
for i in *foo* ;do mv "$i" /tmp/"${i/foo/kuh}";done
```